# Transparent PNG Reacting to Sites Image Sliders and Content

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, transparent, graphical-logo

I just stumbled across this guys site: http://mantia.me/

He has an awesome logo that reacts to the content the site is currently showing, if you wait on his homepage the logo changes with the slide show of images. I was wondering if anyone knows how to replicate the effect. I'm guessing it's a transparent png with a rotating master background then the site is layered on top, but I'm probably wrong.

Any guesses on how to make something similiar?

Images:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really simple what he has. Like you mention it's a transparent PNG that matches the given background ( in this case white ) and places it on top of it with `z-index`. The rest is just jQuery with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` images.

You can view the png on top of the image transitions.
[image]

So basically you just need a `div` with `position:relative` set the width the height of it; then add another `div` inside it which has the jQuery Slideshow (check this out: http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/), set it a `z-index:0` Then add another div (which will go on top of the slider) and add it a `background` with `z-index` to something higher than `0` and you're good to go.

Comment: Please note this is an **explanation**; to make you **understand** how it works. Rather than giving you the complete code (**spoon feeding is bad**). I think it's valuable to understand how it works instead of just copy pasting.

Comment: The key image is the one called "nav.png".

Comment: Indeed. That contains the background with the TEXT form on it.

Comment: Thanks kuroir, I thought it might be to do with z-index. I'm not that well versed with CSS so this helps a bunch. Understanding the theory is 100x better than copying code.

Comment: I'm really glad I could be of service. Kudos for having that way of thinking. Learn as much as you can. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how he does it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="feature"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 64px auto;
    font: normal 13px/16px "myriad-pro-1","myriad-pro-2", sans-serif;
    color: #404040;
}

#navigation{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 46px;
    background: transparent 
      url(http://mantia.me/wp- content/themes/minimalouie/img/nav.png) 
      no-repeat top left;
}

#feature {
    width: 800px;
    height: 466px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

And then he just adds an `img` element to `#feature`.

```
<div id="feature">
    <img src="http://mantia.me/images/supermariobros_large.jpg" 
      alt="Super Mario Bros.">
</div>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mste8/1/).